# The reg queries in for loop are not updating values correctly

Tags: batch-file

I see many good solutions in our site, though of seeking help with what I am struck with.

Below is my code

```
@ECHO Off   
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=D:\new"
SET "destdir=D:\new"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\input.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\output.csv"
(
    FOR /f %%a in (%filename1%) do (
        FOR /L %%s IN (1,1,1) DO SET "col%%s="
        SET col1=%%a
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"') DO SET col2=%%t
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"') DO SET col3=%%t
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"') DO SET col4=%%t
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"') DO SET col5=%%t
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"'') DO SET col6=%%t
        FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"'') DO SET col7=%%t
        ECHO !col1!,!col2!,!col3!,!col4!,!col5!,!col6!,!col7!
    )
)>"%outfile%"
PAUSE
```

---

It all works fine, but if the file has 5 entries, the output for 4 entries will be same as the first entry.
So, only the details for the first entry is right.Next all entries only copy same value as the first entry.
For loop is iterating all the entries in input file, but reg query copies the values of the first iteration.

Can you please help.

Comment: Why do you expect six identical (except for a typo in the last two) `for` commands give non-identical results?

Comment: Are you sure that `tokens=3*` is correct? My understanding is that the second non empty line returned will look like this `#    Date    REG_SZ    SomeString` _(ignoring the leading `#` character which is added just to show the leading spaces in this comment)_. As you can see, the value data is always shown here as `*` if you use `2*` with the space character as a delimiter, not as `3*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your six `for ... %%s` loops are all using the same `%%a`, so of course, you get six identical results. You are supposed to build up the line within the outer loop:

```
@ECHO Off   
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=D:\new"
SET "destdir=D:\new"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\input.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\output.csv"
(
  FOR /f %%a in (%filename1%) do (
    set "col=%%a"
    FOR /f "tokens=3*delims= " %%s IN ('reg query "\\%%a\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\.." /v "Date"') DO (
      SET "col=!col!,%%t"
      ECHO Debug: !col!
    )
    echo !col!
  )
)>"%outfile%"

PAUSE
```

So each `for ... %%s` loop runs with another value of `%%a` and adds the reg-query-result to the string (I left a `echo Debug ...` line just to show you what happens). After the outer loop is done, the string has its final value and can be echoed.

Comment: However, my query was different. Trying to be clear now.The value of the reg query is not what I expect. The outer for loop is taking a remote computer name for the input file. It is supposed to give me the output based on the value in the computer registry path. But it gives wrong output. So I dont know if it is remotely connecting  to wrong computer, or it is displaying some value that is still in the for loop memory(guessing)

Comment: When I echoing to check whether my script is connecting to the correct remote computers in each for loop iteration. I see it is connecting correctly, but the corresponding reg query outputs are incorrect. Strange!!

Comment: Is it something related to SETLOCAL / ENDLOCAL

Comment: When the file contains only one entry (for loop iterates only once), the req query results are as expected. But when the input file contains more than one entry, the  result for all next for loop iterations are same as the first iteration.

Comment: Or this might be because I have some reg queries throwing error?

Comment: you should be able to tell when you run it with `echo on`.

Comment: So this is something with the variables in the inner for loop only i think. Because when i am trying with only 1 entry in the input file, it works. For more than one entry, with echo on, i see its remoting to the correct machine, but the req query value is wrong

Comment: If there is an error in req query, instead of writing blank in csv, I want it to display "No" as text. I think that is causing the issue.How can I do that. Help would be appreciated the most:)

Comment: Any suggestions?